# Zen Cart Product Description Length

Tags: mysql, sql, maxlength, zen-cart

In main product information page, where it shows the full product description, I am trying to put extra long HTML code in to do a package deal. After about 1200 lines of html, I am hitting a wall.

Is there a change I can do to expand the maximum character length of the product description?

(I expanded the product name length by modifying the SQL properties in mySQL. I thought above could be possible a similar way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by:

1. Going in to myPHP
2. Locating Product Description table from the database
3. Changing the type from "TEXT" to "MEDIUMTEXT"